# Show tooltip on hover of whole cell in reactable

Tags: r, reactable

I have a `reactable` in R and I want to display a column that is highlighted in a certain color (in the example below: yellow) and on hover each cell should display a custom tooltip which depends on a hidden (`show = FALSE`) column.

I have managed to do this using a workaround. I need to fill in the cells with HTML non-breaking spaces `&nbsp;` and on hover of those space characters the tooltip is displayed.

This is not optimal, since I want the tooltip to show on hover of the whole cell and not only on hover of the spaces which are located in the cell center.

Here is my setup:

```r
library(shiny)
library(tippy)
library(reactable)
library(dplyr)


# Data
data <-  iris[1:5,] %>%
  mutate(Tooltip_display = "",
         Tooltip_column = paste0('Tooltip ', row_number(), '<br>This text is long and should <br> show up when hovering'))
```

This is my current workaround:

```r
# Working
render.reactable.cell.with.tippy <- function(text, tooltip){
  div(
    style = "cursor: info;
             white-space: nowrap;
             overflow: hidden;
             text-overflow: ellipsis;
            ",
    tippy(text = paste(rep("&nbsp;", 16), collapse = " "), tooltip = tooltip)
  )
}

reactable(data,
          columns = list(
            
            Tooltip_display = colDef(
              html = TRUE,
              cell =  function(value, index, name) {
                render.reactable.cell.with.tippy(text = value, tooltip = data[index,]$Tooltip_column)
                },
              style = list(background = "yellow")
            ),
            
            Tooltip_column = colDef(show = FALSE)
          ))
```

I thought, that I could use the `style` argument in `colDef` and supply a similar function from the {tippy} package which doesn't use `text` as argument but styles a whole `div`. Unfortunately, this is not working (see below).

Any help appreciated!

```r
# Not working
render.reactable.cell.with.tippy <- function(tooltip){
  with_tippy(
    div(
      style = "cursor: info;
               white-space: nowrap;
               overflow: hidden;
               text-overflow: ellipsis;
               background: yellow;
              "),
    tooltip = tooltip
    )
}



reactable(data,
          columns = list(
            
            Tooltip_display = colDef(
              html = TRUE,
              style = function(value, index) {
                render.reactable.cell.with.tippy(tooltip = data[index,]$Tooltip_column) 
              }
            
            Tooltip_column = colDef(show = FALSE)
          ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `with_tippy` function has to be called in the `cell` argument of `colDef` and the `div` element needs to be set `height: 100%` otherwise the `div` won't be displayed. Then we have to remove the `padding` around the cell content and we can do this by setting `padding: 0` in the `style` argument of `colDef`.

```r
reactable(data,
          columns = list(
            
            Tooltip_display = colDef(
              html = TRUE,
              cell =  function(value, index, name) {
                with_tippy(
                  div(
                    style = "cursor: info;
               white-space: nowrap;
               overflow: hidden;
               height: 100%;
               background: yellow;
              "),
              tooltip = data[index,]$Tooltip_column
                )
              },
              style =
                
                list(background = "yellow", padding = 0)
            ),
            
            Tooltip_column = colDef(show = FALSE)
          ))
```

Comment: For some reason when I use this solution it slows down my shiny app like a crazy amount. Any idea why that is? There are a little over 3,000 rows. In addition, the contents don't show up just the tooltip. o_O.

Comment: @ethantenison: Regarding speed I cannot really help you, since my own use cases have less than 100 rows and there is no speed issue there. However, my solution above runs sometimes into trouble not displaying the tooltip and I haven't figured out yet why this is happening. If you can create a minimal example for your problem and post it as a question I gladly give it a look.